# All items that match all the words in a collection

Tags: linq

I have two lists: a list of type Person and a list of type profession. Both are many-to-many related. 
In addition, I have a third list with some professions.
I would like to select all persons that match all the professions in the third list. 
What would be LINQ/Lambda expression?

Thanks

Comment: Share your code, please

Comment: Please show what you have tried? Also is it an in memory collection or to some DB. If the latter then which framework?

Comment: You've provided no detail here at all.  Have you tried to solve the problem?  What results did you get?  Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how your sequence of `Persons` are connected to your sequence of `Professions`.

You are talking about Lists, but also about many-to-many relation, so I assume your lists are in fact tables in a relational database, with a joining table that remembers which Persons and Professions are related.

If you use entity framework, and you have set-up the [many-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) correctly you don't need the third table:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Person has zero or more Professions (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Profession> Professions {get; set;}
}

class Profession
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every Profession has zero or more Persons (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons {get; set;}
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Profession> Professions {get; set;}
}
```

That is all!

Entity Framework will recognize that you are modeling a many-to-many relationship and will create the third table for it. You don't need this third table, just access the ICollections, and entity framework will automatically perform the required joins with the third table.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    IEnumerable<Profession> professionList = ... // the third list

    // Keep only the persons where have exactly all Professions from the profession list
    // do this by checking the Ids of the professions in the list
    IEnumerable<int> professionIds = professions
        .Select(profession => profession.Id)
        .OrderBy(id => id);

    var personsWithProfessions = dbContext.Persons
        // keep only persons that have the same Profession Ids as professionIds
        // first extract the the profession Ids the person has
        .Where(person => person.Professions
             .Select(profession => profession.Id)
             // order this in ascending order
             .OrderBy(id => id)
             // check if equal to professionIds:
             .SequenceEqual(professionIds))
```

If you are not using Entity Framework, or the classes are not set-up properly with the virtual ICollection, you'll have to do the join between `Persons` and `Professions` yourself

Assuming you have a joining table that joins your Persons and Professions:

```
class Person_Profession
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public int PersonId {get; set;}
     public int ProfessionId {get; set;}
}
IQueryable<Person_Profession> Person_Profession_Table = ...
```

First group every person with all ProfessionIds in the Person_Profession_Table.

```
var personsWithProfessionIds = Persons.GroupJoin(person_profession_table,
   person => person.Id,
   personProfession => personProfession.PersonId,
   person, matchingJoiningItems => new
   {
       Person = person,
       ProfessionIds = matchingJoiningItems
           .Select(matchingJoiningItem => matchingJoiningItem.ProfessionId)
           .OrderBy(id => id)
           .ToList(),
   })
```

In words: take the two tables: Persons and PersonProfessions. From every person take the Id, from every personProfession element take the PersonId, for every person and all matching personProfessions make one new object: this object contains the matching Person, and all ProfessionIds of the matching joiningItems.

From these Persons with their ProfessionIds, keep only those Persons that have all ProfessionIds in your third list

```
IEnumerable<int> professionIds = professions
        .Select(profession => profession.Id)
        .OrderBy(id => id);
IEnumerable<Person> matchingPersons = personsWithProfessionIds
    .Where(personWithProfessionId => personWithProfessioinId.ProfessionIds
    .SequenceEqual(professiondIds))
    .Select(personWithProfessionId => perfonWithProfessionId.Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `List`s are related by containing member `List`s of the other type,

```
var AllPersons = new List<Person>();
var AllProfessions = new List<Profession>();
var desiredProfessions = new List<Profession>();

var findPersons = from p in AllPersons
                  where p.Professions.Any(pp => desiredProfessions.Contains(pp))
                  select p;
```